# Correct order of parallel execution of shell `time` command

Tags: macos, shell, gnu-parallel, optimathsat

I need to execute the command below (as part of a script) but I don't know in what order to put things so that it executes correctly. What I am trying to do is to give **file.smt2** as input to  **optimathsat**, execute it, get the execution time.  But I want this to be done several times in parallel using all CPU cores.

```
parallel -j+0 time Desktop/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2 &>results.csv
```

I added `#!/bin/bash -x` at the beginning of my file to look at what is happening and this was the output:

```
+ parallel -j+0 time file.smt2
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. You are either an expert
parallel: Warning: (in which case: YOU ARE AWESOME!) or maybe you forgot.
parallel: Warning: ::: or :::: or -a or to pipe data into parallel.
```

...from the 1st line, I can tell the order is wrong. From line 2,3 and 4 the syntax is lacking.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Hint: `foo bar > baz` redirects the output of `foo bar` to overwrite the file *baz*.

Comment: @agc I have fixed the typo. I know that > is usually for redirection. the documentation of Optimathsat suggests this way.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it you do not care about the results, but only the timing:

```
seq $(parallel --number-of-threads) |
  parallel -j+0 -N0 --joblog my.log 'Desktop/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2'
cat my.log
```

`-N0` inserts 0 arguments.

Consider reading GNU Parallel 2018 ([printed](https://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html), [online](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)) - at least chapter 1+2. Your command line will thank you for it.